Confusion with the word "join"
Take a look at this sentence:
"Enjolras had been joined by his friends to the party"
How can I know it's Enjolras himself who is invited by his friends to the party or it's Enjolras' friends who come to Enjolras which is already on the party?

Where did you get that sentence? Look up the verb: join.

This sentence doesn't make a lot of sense without any context. Is it party as in a social event or a group of people (hunting/fighting party)? Whose party is it?

The sentence doesn't make total sense as is. When we use "join" along with "to," it's normally a different meaning, as in "I joined the leg to the table." His friends didn't glue him to the party. What's probably intended is:

Enjolras had been joined by his friends at the party

None of which answers your core question, which is who got to the party first. There are two possible meanings and one impossible one (and hopefully the context would clarify). The construction "X was joined by Y" means "Y was added to X." This can either mean that both Enjolras and his friends reached the party at the same time, or that Enjolras was there first and then the friends came. But it wouldn't be the right expression if the friends were there first; if that were the case, you might turn the verb around, saying "Enjolras joined his friends."
